# AirPods don't work when connected to external monitor - sometimes

Tags: display, audio, webcam, airpods

I received a set of AirPods for the holidays and I'm generally enjoying using them with my 15-inch MacBook Pro (2018), which is running High Sierra (10.13.6).

This MBP only has USB-C ports. Four of them. I'm using an Apple 27-inch Thunderbolt display that has an Apple adapter to convert to the USB-C.

If I'm listening to music - for example on YouTube - the AirPods work just fine. I get audio and it sounds great. When I try to use Google Hangouts with video sourced from the external monitor's camera, the video works just fine but I get no audio with the AirPods. If I disconnect from the external monitor and use a video Hangout sourcing the video from the built-in camera, the AirPods work just fine. If I use the Hangout without audio at all, the AirPods work just fine, too.

Considering this, it seems like there's something breaking whenever I'm getting video from the external monitor.

#### Is there something about my setup that would prevent the audio from working in this situation?

---

Other notes:

- I have a set of wireless headphones that have a USB dongle that I plug into the monitor and this works just fine, too (assuming I remember to turn them on).
- I've not tried to use the AirPods when connected to the external monitor but using the built-in camera on the MBP.

Comment: What do you see in `System Preferences` > `Sound` > `Output` when you're not getting audio?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it shows the AirPods listed and selected (memory can be a bit wonky and I don't have a way to test it right this second). I'm pretty sure I've tried to switch it to something else and back and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of poking at this, I've managed to figure it out.

This actually had *nothing* to do with the AirPods or the external monitor, rather the problem was that Google Hangouts has its own settings to choose which devices are being used for input/output that overrides the system settings. So, while I was frantically trying to change which device was supplying in/out in the system preferences, Hangouts was happily sitting on the devices it had chosen, ignoring those changes.

Once I realized what was going on, changing the setting manually in Hangouts from my other wireless headphones to the AirPods proves effective every time.